# What's the Clock Pulse measure?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm new in computer architecture and I can't understand what's the `clock` or `clock pulse` measurement in CPU and refers to which operation in computer?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? There is a global clock signal in the CPU (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_signal) which is often called frequency of the CPU. (there are also clocks in every data bus around CPU). But there can be logical measurement from some program (code) or physical measurement with oscilloscope and high-speed probe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WTPC_Oscilloscope-1.jpg), connecting to motherboard.

Answer (score -1):

1. What is Clock Pulse
2. What is the between  S-R and clock S-R
3. What do the you understand  by ridge of Clock  pulse
4. Have you face any problem in the experiment discuses detail
5. Vary the input A & B to obtain all the possible combination and caked truth table for the sum output S and the carry output C
6. Way is the Half adder not sweat able for all addition operation. Way do we need a full adder
7. What does it mean by C. What was the actual output voltage for the input to the full adder where valuage A, B and C are 1
8. What is the difference Half and Full Adder.

Comment: Please describe the answer.